Conversion from MJy/Sr to Jy or erg/s/Hz/cm² for JWST NIRCAM image
I have JWST NIRCAM image. The unit are in MJy/Sr. I would like to convert to either Jy or erg/s/Hz/cm². I tried many ways but I am not sure it is true or false.
MJy/sr → Jy conversion:
1 MJy = 10⁶ Jy
Need to multiply by pixel area in steradians (sr)
JWST pixel scale = 0.06 arcsec/pixel
Pixel area = (0.06 × 4.8481E-6)² sr
(where 4.8481E-6 is conversion from arcsec to radians)
Then Jy → erg/s/Hz/cm²:
1 Jy = 10⁻²³ erg/s/Hz/cm²
I would like to confirm this is correct?
I also have WHT and Sigma image. For these, how to convert?
Please let me know. Thank you so much.
